# How can multiple users query a SQL table using a parameter passed into a textbox on a VB.NET form without overwritting each others results

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a SQL table, 'ClientInvoices'

```
InvoiceNo | ClientNo | ClientName | Amount
  1       |     C100 |    John    |  10000
  2       |     C101 |    Jane    |  50000
  3       |     C102 |    James   |  40000
```

I run a query on the table which takes a parameter passed from a textbox on a vb.net form. The results are then inserted into another sorting table: 'SortedInvoices'. The data in the'SortedInvoices' table is then what is use to create a crystal report.
I use the Code below to pick data from the 'ClientInvoices' table into the 'SortedInvoices'

```
 myconnection.Open()
 Dim mycommand2 As New SqlCommand("delete View_ClientSelectedInvoices", myconnection)
    mycommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SortedInvoices (InvoiceNo,ClientNo,ClientName,Amount)SELECT MInvoiceNo,ClientNo,ClientName,Amount FROM ClientInvoices WHERE ClientInvoices.InvoiceNo = '" & TxtInvoiceNo.Text & "' ", myconnection)
    mycommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myconnection.Close()
```

If a value of '1' is typed into the textbox, the 'sortedInvoices' table will have the following data:

```
InvoiceNo | ClientNo | ClientName | Amount
  1       |     C100 |    John    |  10000
```

From the code you can see that before new data is inserted into the 'SortedInvoices' table, all existing data has to first be deleted.
My application is going to be on a LAN, the challenge with that approach is that if multiple users from different workstations run that query, they will end up overwriting each other's data hence getting wrong results in the crystal report. I am trying to find way of each user being able to view exactly what they queried based on the textbox value without having to delete existing data first from the 'sortedInvoices' table.

I have tried using views but I have failed to pass parameters to the view from the textbox. I tried temporary tables but the challenge with them is that I cannot pass the temporary table to Crystal Report.

I am requesting any help on how to achieve this.
Any sample code to help me is highly appreciated.
NOTE: I am new to programming

Comment: Show some code. There are many ways to do this, so we need to see something of what you have as a starting point so we can provide a solution that will make sense to you.

Comment: Why do you need to copy this data into an existing table?  Why not just use a in memory DataTable object in your application to display the query results?  Is there some other processing you need to do?  And please use parameters rather than string concatenation for your query command

Comment: Please refer in the first instance to http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: In line with hursey's comment, I concur; a Crystal Report can use a DataTable as a report data source, so you can run the query and download the data, maybe even manipulate it further, then give it to the report. See something like https://www.codeproject.com/articles/28899/crystal-report-with-dataset-and-datatable-using-c - it's been a long time since I worked with CR, but it seems familiar, with the exception that I don't recall using strongly typed datatables, only base ones

Comment: There's a lot wrong here. Firstly, calling `ExecuteNonQuery` to execute a query is wrong. In this case, you should be calling `ExecuteReader` and then calling `Load` on a `DataTable` to populate it from the data reader. Secondly, you should learn how to use parameters with ADO.NET to pass the values into your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: May be my question was not clear, let me edit it with examples

Comment: Yeah, you might of updated your question some, but still don't see the point of writing this all out to another DB table simply to pull it all out again to report it.  If you insist on saving this to a DB table about the only thing I can think of you can do is also give it a session/user token to identify who has created the records, then ONLY delete records for the selected session/user.

Comment: "writing this all out to another DB table simply to pull it all out again to report it." this is what am trying to avoid, I am trying to find a more intelligent way of passing the data requested by each user depending on the parameter entered into the textbox to a report.

Comment: Well the more intelligent way is to read your data into an in memory datatable object then use that as the data source for your report.  Have a read up on ado.net on best usage for query your data and then the link CaiusJard gave you on how to get it into a report

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution by using a stored procedure.
I do not have to sort data by transferring it from table A to table B, i use a stored procedure which i then pass to the crystal report with parameters.
Thanks for the tips